# What is the design pattern for forwarding messages to a centralised object?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, amazon-sqs, observer-pattern, factory-pattern

**What is the design pattern for forwarding messages to a centralised object?**

I have to select few messages from UI and forward them to a centralized service like SQS.
What is the most accurate design pattern that can be used for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the architecture principles used in the modern world pub-sub based interactions between systems. This is based on the assumption that the UI component has the capability of making an API call and act accordingly based on the response received from the backend components.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. But my question revolves around the design pattern which could help in implementation.

Comment: This is based on pub sub design pattern. The benefit of this pattern is that the source (UI in this case) will be able to send messages to multiple destinations. There is no need to change application code if there is a need to add a new destination for the messages.